# How to apply PermWrapper proxy in Django correctly

Tags: django, python-2.7

I got the error message: "'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'" when using PermWrapper for the RBAC control in my application.

I traced into `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.py` and found that sometimes what passed in *user* parameter is a whole WSGIRequest object rather than the user object inside WSGIRequest object.

```
class PermWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
```

so later when it runs to **bool** function of *PermLookupDict* class, *self.user* is a *WSGIRequest* and would not have 'has_module_perms' function to invoke, therefore throws an exception.

```
class PermLookupDict(object):
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.user.has_module_perms(self.module_name)
```

Have anybody ever ran into similar issue? What am I missing here? My temporary workaround is to change `self.user.has_module_perms` to `self.user.user.has_module_perms` in `__bool__` function.

I'm using Django 1.5, and my settings file looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'a10ext.context_processors.a10ext',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my settings.py I have this in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as well:

```
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"
```